# youtube search api - too much data, can I limit what nodes the api returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

can I somehow limit the ammount of nodes that the json object returns? I'm only using title, author and video id from each of the search results , so I have no need to load and parse a million other nodes. Anyway of doing this besides running it thought a server side proxy?

Comment: No, not really. You could use a service such as YQL, but that's just a server-side proxy that happens to not be your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why everyone is saying no, because while you can't limit it to JUST title, channelId, and videoId, you can choose to leave some fields out. There is a "fields" parameter that you can use in v3 of the Data Api.  [Check out the documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Response without fields set:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"a6IVtoIjS7Yw-1cFQOGQ6_bjjs4/_DFSOhdxHuGG_p_f1fVZOosZghs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "dw1HavgoK9E"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"a6IVtoIjS7Yw-1cFQOGQ6_bjjs4/aY_GfDmiGidcZL_TBO7vI8YP9XY\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-02-15T09:38:27.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvZuIe7j7oBfaWAL0sO3JzQ",
    "title": "Drivers stoned on marijuana test their driving skills",
    "description": "If you watched this video and liked Addy, you can watch outtakes of her here: http://kiro.tv/WFNEMZ CNN may have just posted their best piece of investigativ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

API Call: [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=1&q=test&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=1&q=test&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

Response with fields set:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "dw1HavgoK9E"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-02-15T09:38:27.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvZuIe7j7oBfaWAL0sO3JzQ",
    "title": "Drivers stoned on marijuana test their driving skills",
    "description": "If you watched this video and liked Addy, you can watch outtakes of her here: http://kiro.tv/WFNEMZ CNN may have just posted their best piece of investigativ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dw1HavgoK9E/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

API Call: [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=1&q=test&fields=items(id%2Csnippet)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=1&q=test&fields=items%28id,snippet%29&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. going throught a proxy doesn't seem a good idea. If you're just thinking, I'm wasting bandwith, let's cut it down, then you can't. ;)

Comment: Good news is you're not wasting your bandwidth, just your client's bandwidth. :p

Comment: bandwidth is not really an issue, its the overblown DOM that bothers me